# Create second table in mySQL with trigger include some conditions

Tags: mysql

I have Mysql `table1` and create trigger to make another `table2` when new row is inserted. This work fine and now I have two identical tables :). I want to make some changes (conditions) when second table is created.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `listener` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `table2` (column1, column2,column3, column4) VALUES (new.column1, new.column2, new.column3, new.column4)
```

I'm trying to include into trigger some conditions before `table2` is created.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2,.......) VALUES (new.val1, new.val2....)
WHERE column1 LIKE '%name1%' OR LIKE '%name2%'
```

Comment: Creating a new table from a trigger sounds like an all-around bad idea. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have a server which one logging messages in mySQL. First table will be for all messages (like a history) and the second will be for the things that I'm interesting and I want to monitor(like alarms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `INSERT SELECT` from `dual`:

```
INSERT INTO table2
           (column1,
            column2,
            ...)
           SELECT new.val1,
                  new.val2,
                  ...
                  FROM dual
                  WHERE new.val1 LIKE '%name1%'
                         OR new.val1 LIKE '%name2%';
```

Or simply an `IF`:

```
IF new.val1 LIKE '%name1%'
    OR new.val1 LIKE '%name2%' THEN
  INSERT ...;
END IF;
```